# How to optimize nested CASE statements in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, conditional-statements, case

I am quite new to PL/SQL.
I am using the following nested CASE statement in a SELECT query. This follows the WHERE clause.
However, the query takes about 6 minutes to complete because of this nesting. If at least one CASE block is removed the query only takes about 1 minute to complete. 
Is there any way to optimize this query?

```
(case
 when a = 'STAGE PAYMENT' then
 'Y'
 when b not IN ('To be Received', 'Received') then
 'N'
 when c != (d - NVL(e, 0) - NVL(f, 0) - NVL(g, 0)) then
 'Y'
 when NVL(h, 0) + NVL(i, 0) + NVL(j, 0) <> 0 then
    case 
    when c != k then
    'Y'
    when (-l != NVL(e, 0) + NVL(f, 0) + NVL(g, 0) + NVL(m, 0)) then
    'Y' 
    else 'N'
    end 
 else 'N'
 end = 'Y')
```

I have tried using IF-ELSE blocks, but it did not do any good.

Comment: At least this: `when b not IN ('To be Received', 'Received') then 'N'`, is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you! But when it is removed, the results from the query also changes.

The original query gives 1906 rows as the result and after removing the condition you mentioned, the query result is 5497 rows.

Comment: You say: *This follows the WHERE clause* so the statement is: `WHERE <CAS...> = 'Y'`. If you remove that part, there is also: `ELSE 'N'` at the end and this will be returned in the case `b not IN ('To be Received', 'Received')`. So it is redundant. Unless you use the code differently.

Comment: Are all the conditions mutually exclusive?If not then the condition should not be removed.

Comment: The conditions are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

What about aggregating the nested cases in the parent case with ANDs?

```
(case
 when a = 'STAGE PAYMENT' then
 'Y'
 when b not IN ('To be Received', 'Received') then
 'N'
 when c != (d - NVL(e, 0) - NVL(f, 0) - NVL(g, 0)) then
 'Y'
 when NVL(h, 0) + NVL(i, 0) + NVL(j, 0) <> 0 and c != k then
 'Y'
 when NVL(h, 0) + NVL(i, 0) + NVL(j, 0) <> 0 and (-l != NVL(e, 0) + NVL(f, 0) + NVL(g, 0) + NVL(m, 0)) then
 'Y'
 -- this serves as else 'N' in your code  
 when NVL(h, 0) + NVL(i, 0) + NVL(j, 0) <> 0 then
 'N'
 else 'N'
 end = 'Y')
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but adding in `when NVL(h, 0) + NVL(i, 0) + NVL(j, 0) <> 0` for each condition is repetitive and is redundant. It increases the time taken to complete the query (6 mins and 30 secs approximately) even though one CASE block can be removed.